# In sharepoint,to get other user profile which sharepoint webservice should use?

Tags: user-profile

I want to get other user's profile details like email, id, work phone, home phone, department, title etc... By using  which webservice/method, can I get this informtions? I tried with `UserProfileService.GetUserProfileByName()` method, but it is giving profile information of same user who configured it, not other user's (who shared items) profile.

Comment: Can you please submit your code? It makes it easier to understand what you are doing, where, and any possible errors

Comment: What version of SharePoint? 2010 and 2013 have different approaches. GetUserProfileByName() will return the calling user. You have to pass the user account in order to get another user. If 2013 use REST and not SOAP.